# list known mac-addresses on Dell PowerConnect 5324

Tags: mac-address, dell-powerconnect

I have a Dell PowerConnect 5324 (SW version:  2.0.1.3) which I hardly ever use.  I need to list out the mac-addresses it sees on certain ports, such as g23.  I have fooled around with the cli and done a few google searches, but have not run across the exact command to do this.  The switch is only accessible via the serial port & cli.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
redacted# show system 
...
Type:                                     PowerConnect 5324
redacted# show version 
SW version    2.0.1.3 ( date  04-Mar-2008 time  10:55:29 )
redacted# show mac-address-table
% Unrecognized command
```

( 'show mac-address-table' is a Cisco thing. )

```
redacted# show bridge address-table 
Aging time is 300 sec

  Vlan        Mac Address       Port     Type    
-------- --------------------- ------ ---------- 
   1       00:44:a5:AA:BB:CC    g22    dynamic   
   1       00:33:e9:DD:EE:FF    g22    dynamic   
   1       00:22:db:CC:BB:AA    g22    dynamic   
   1       00:11:29:EE:FF:00    g22    dynamic
```

...

You can also filter by port (show bridge address table ethernet g1) and by address on this model. Other (newer!) PowerConnect models have more limited options, which is somewhat annoying.

Comment: `show bridge address-table` is on older devices and the 35xx series. `sh mac address-table` is on newer devices (5548, etc)

Answer (score 3):

What about the command:

```
 show mac-address-table
```

> Use this command to view classes of entries in the bridge-forwarding database.

Syntax

show mac-address-table [address mac-address [mask]] [interface interface] [vlan vlan-id] [sort {address | vlan | interface}]

mac-address - MAC address.
mask - Bits to match in the address.
interface
ethernet unit/port
unit - This is device 1.
port - Port number.
port-channel channel-id (Range: 1-6)
vlan-id - VLAN ID (Range: 1-4094)
sort - Sort by address, vlan or interface.
Default Setting

None

Command Mode

Privileged Exec

Command Usage

The MAC Address Table contains the MAC addresses associated with each interface.
The Type field may include the following types:
 - Learned - dynamic address entries
 - Permanent - static entry
Delete-on-reset - static entry to be deleted when system is reset
The mask should be hexadecimal numbers (representing an equivalent bit mask) in the form xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx that is applied to the specified MAC address. Enter hexadecimal numbers, where an equivalent binary bit “0” means to match a bit and “1” means to ignore a bit. For example, a mask of 00-00-00-00-00-00 means an exact match, and a mask of FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF means "any."
The maximum number of address entries -
PowerConnect 3248: 8191
PowerConnect 5224: 32768
Example
[image]
[Dell Support](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/pc5212/CLIG/address.htm)

Comment: This was the proper command for 3.1.0.16.